# A condition on the inequality $f'(x)/(1-f(x)^2)-1/(1-x^2)\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

Assume that $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is an diffeomorphism so that $(f''(x)/f'(x))'<0$ and that $f''(0)=0$. It seems to me that $$\frac{1-f(x)^2}{1-x^2}\le f'(x)$$ on $[0,1]$. But no proof so far.

The answer posted below is correct. I however need $f$ to be increasing.

Comment: I think it could help if you disclose the origins of this problem.

Comment: You now have a positive answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/422460/36721 assuming $f$ is increasing. Again, can you disclose the origins of this problem?

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis  Many thanks. I have detailed the answer to your email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\in[0,1]$, let
\begin{equation*}
    f(x):=c\int_x^1 e^{-t^2}\,dt,
\end{equation*}
where $c:=1/\int_0^1 e^{-t^2}\,dt$.
Then $f\colon[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is a diffeomorphism such that $(f''(x)/f'(x))'<0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $f''(0)=0$.
However, the inequality in question,
\begin{equation*}
    L(x):=\frac{1-f(x)^2}{1-x^2}\le f'(x), \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
fails to hold for any $x\in[0,1]$, since $f'<0$ and $L>0$ on $[0,1)$, whereas $L(1)$ is undefined.

Comment: I forgot to put the condition that $f$ is increasung.

Comment: @Provoj1 : One should not change the question so as to to invalidate a valid answer. Therefore, I suggest you restore the original question. Then you may want to post a changed question elsewhere, possibly not on MathOverflow.